# Run a command as the standard user, from a sudo elevated script

Tags: macos, bash, shell, sudo

If a bash script has been executed with sudo, how can a command within the script run as the currently logged in user, instead of root and then revert to root to continue running other commands?

For example: -

```
#!/usr/bash

touch fileOwnedByRoot.txt
touch fileOwnedByUser.txt
touch otherRootFile.txt
```

If this script is run with sudo, without changing the order of commands, how can the 2nd touch command be run as the standard user?

The script is only a simple example, so using chmod to change ownership of files created is irrelevant.

The actual script I'm using is being run by an installer, so running with elevated privileges is a requirement, but specific commands must be run as the user running the installer, whose name is not known.

Comment: There is no "standard user"; do you mean as the user who ran `sudo` in the first place?

Comment: @chepner Yes, the user responsible for calling the script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `su - another_user -c "<command>"` to run that specific command:

```
#!/bin/bash

touch /tmp/f1
su - another_user -c "touch /tmp/f2"
touch /tmp/f3
```

---

As commented by [chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner) below, you need to use `$SUDO_USER` or `$SUDO_UID` to get the name of the real user running the `sudo` command:

```
su - $SUDO_USER -c "touch /tmp/f2"
```

This way, the file will be touched by the user running the command.

You can test with:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "sudo_user: $SUDO_USER"
echo "sudo_uid: $SUDO_UID"
```

And run the script either with `./script` or `sudo ./script`. In the second case the values will be populated.

Comment: Sorry, I've explained a little more clearly in an edit to the question; I don't know who the current user is running the script. How would this be specified here?

Comment: `sudo` sets `$SUDO_USER` to the user name of the person calling `sudo`. There are also `$SUDO_UID` and `$SUDO_GID` if necessary.

Comment: @Merlin069 see the comment by chepner!

Answer (score 5):

Don't run the script as `sudo`, just the commands that require elevated privileges.

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo touch fileOwnedByRoot.txt
touch fileOwnedByUser.txt
sudo touch otherRootFile.txt
```

Comment: I would normally agree, but the script is a post install script, which is run as root by default and some of the commands must be run with elevated privileges, while others can not, such as running a service

Answer (score 2):

According to the [man page](http://www.gratisoft.us/sudo/man/sudo.html) the environment variable SUDO_USER is set when you run sudo, so you could do something like:

```
#!/usr/bash

touch fileOwnedByRoot.txt
sudo ${SUDO_USER} touch fileOwnedByUser.txt
touch otherRootFile.txt
```

I haven't tested this, and don't know if it work differently on OSX, but it's worth a shot.